# Cascading DropDownList is not populated in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to dynamically populate a dropdownlist. I have a table of District{district_id,distrint_name} and Thana{thana_id,thana_name,district_id(fk)}.

The controller code:

```
public class CenterController : Controller
{    
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CenterConnString"].ConnectionString;
    List<SelectListItem> districtList = new List<SelectListItem>();      
    List<SelectListItem> thanaList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.var1 = DistrictList();
        ViewBag.var2 = thanaList;        

        return View();
    }

    private SelectList DistrictList()  
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select distrint_name,district_id from tbl_district ", conn);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                districtList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = myReader["distrint_name"].ToString(), Value = myReader["district_id"].ToString() });
            }
        }
        return new SelectList(districtList, "Value", "Text", "id"); //return the list objects in json form
    }

    public JsonResult ThanaList(int id)  
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_thana where district_id ='" + id + "' ", conn);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                thanaList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = myReader["thana_name"].ToString(), Value = myReader["thana_id"].ToString() });
            }
        }
        return Json(thanaList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //return the list objects in json form
    }
}
```

View code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>

District          @Html.DropDownList("var1", "Choose District")
Thana             @Html.DropDownList("var2", "Choose Thana")
                                   @*dropdown with name var1, var2,var3 and with viewbag object*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    //initial var2, var3 are empty
    //dropdownlist name and viewbag object name must be same

    $(function () {
        $("#var1").change(function () {
            var name = $("#var1 :selected").val();  //if user select the tournament
            var url = 'Home/DistrictList';
            var data1 = { "id": name };
            $.post(url, data1, function (data) { //ajax call
                var items = [];
                items.push("<option value=" + 0 + ">" + "Choose Thana" + "</option>"); //first item
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    items.push("<option value=" + data[i].Value + ">" + data[i].Text + "</option>");
                } //all data from the team table push into array
                $("#var2").html(items.join(' '));
            }); //array object bind to dropdown list
        });
});

</script>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

The problem is that District list is populated ok.But the second ddl is not binding anything. By debugging it is seen that the code does not run through "Viewbag.var2=thanalist". it's not calling Thanalist(int id) method.
I cant get rid of the error.please help.

Comment: According to your code, why do you think that `Viewbag.var2 = thanalist` should call `Thanalist(int id)`?

Comment: i am describing what is happening here..Plz find me the bug.2nd ddl is not populating.what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest to you is first to read some articles about cascading dropdowns (this is very common thing to do). You will probably find the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249335/connecting-between-two-dropdownlist-mvc-4). If you want to see more detailed version with some good practices, then check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A).

Looking at your code I will take responsibility to give you few advises:

1. Move your database code to separate class. If you continue to keep it in controller action methods they will become very messy.
2. Use `Model` not `ViewBag`. In your particular example there is no any benefit of using `ViewBag`.

**EDIT:**
It's not easy to understand what you want to achieve, but I guess that you want to have some `District` selected by default and `Thana` list to be populated too.

Here is an example of how it can be done.

Models and demo data access layer:

```
public class District
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Thana
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    public IEnumerable<District> GetDistricts()
    {
        // Dome data
        return new List<District>
        {
            new District {Id = 1, Text = "D1"},
            new District {Id = 2, Text = "D2"}
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Thana> GetThanas(int districtId)
    {
        // Demo data
        if (districtId == 1)
        {
            return new List<Thana> { new Thana {Id = 1, Text = "T11"}, new Thana {Id = 2, Text = "T12"}};
        }

        return new List<Thana> { new Thana {Id = 3, Text = "T21"}, new Thana {Id = 4, Text = "T22"} };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public SelectList Districts { get; set; }
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }

    public SelectList Thanas { get; set; }
    public int ThanaId { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly Repository _repository = new Repository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Should be refactored to handle empty collections
        var districts = _repository.GetDistricts().ToList();
        var firstDistrict = districts.First();
        var thanas = _repository.GetThanas(firstDistrict.Id).ToList();
        var firstThana = thanas.First();

        var vm = new IndexViewModel
        {
            Districts = new SelectList(districts, "Id", "Text", firstDistrict),
            DistrictId = firstDistrict.Id,
            Thanas = new SelectList(thanas, "Id", "Text", firstThana),
            ThanaId = firstThana.Id
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult GetThanas(int districtId)
    {
        return Json(_repository.GetThanas(districtId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IndexViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DistrictId, Model.Districts)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ThanaId, Model.Thanas)

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#DistrictId").change(function () {
                var self = $(this);
                var items="";
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetThanas","Home")?districtId=" + self.val(),
                    function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                            items += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.Text
                                + "</option>";
                        });
                        $("#ThanaId").html(items);
                    });
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

Comment: these are not my answer to the question. i know the convention to use model insted of viewbag. it's a story of a huge project and this code will be modified and merged afterwards. Now try to solve the bug. thnx in advance. i have been through these links before u suggested them.@Aleksandr